# Prohibiting questions from starting with "so"

Tags: discussion

I see a definite trend in questions, at least on Stack Overflow, starting with the word "So". Unfortunately, this means nothing, is irrelevant, distracting, and irritating. It is ranked #2 on the "[NPR Grammar Hall Of Shame](http://www.npr.org/2014/12/30/372495062/the-npr-grammar-hall-of-shame-opens-with-i-and-me)".

How can we stamp out this annoying practice?

Comment: So, we should be taking advice from NPR now, should we?

Comment: *First!...* Srsly how many annoying Idiosyncrazies can U rly dis automagically in codez? cuz 1337 5p34k GIVE ME AND US LULZ!!!!!!!1111 :P

Comment: Discrimination against valley girls

Comment: Related: [So, how do you feel about "so" on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174229)

Comment: If it bugs you so much just edit it out. 'prohibiting' things things like that is overkill.

Comment: So, do you think "so" is the biggest problem on SO titles? So, you'd be surprised.

Comment: And when will the American patriots start editing all my British English posts, I wonder?

Answer (score 11):

> How can we stamp out this annoying practice?

You have the power!!!

Oh, yeah. You do.

Suggest an edit to remove the word and make the question/answer a better one. With enough reputation (2000 on graduated sites), you can just edit without the edits requiring approval.

A post that begins thus is likely to require some more help, so the 6 character minimum for an edit should be easy to reach.

Comment: Please don't suggest people make pointless edits.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making an excessive list of all the bad ways to start a question or answer, it is better to leave it to the community (and also often less annoying when dealing with false positives).

Anyone can suggest an edit or even edit directly if you have enough reputation as Oded explained.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed these "So"s creeping in as well, and they are irritating, however...

Having such annoyances removed, automatically by software, can result in a number of unknown, and undesired automatic edits happening, so it is better to rely on the human eye, manual editing and common sense - unfortunately.

The [answer](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/automatic-replace-in-questions#answer-1289) to a similar question, [Automatic replace in questions](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/automatic-replace-in-questions), on SE Arduino brings up some valid points.

Comment: I didn't suggest automatically removing them. I asked what to do about them. Valid answers to that question include automatically removing them, doing nothing, manually editing them, marking the initial "so" with a flashing pink background, putting up a non-intrusive message confirming that the OP wants to begin his post with "so', etc. etc. More basically this question was a sardonic comment on the horrible grammar, spelling, and punctuation (don't get me started on "it's" vs. "its") in posts and the inability to do anything about it.

Comment: @torazaburo - I agree wholeheartedly with you, that is why _I_ actually up voted you :-) Take a peek at the Addendum of my Arduino meta question, [A rash of minor edits](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/2332/a-rash-of-minor-edits). The list of bad habits in posts is endless... I like your suggestion of a non-intrusive message, or flashing pink background. You should edit your question and put them in as suggestions, as you hadn't mentioned anything like that.

Comment: In addition, the vehement opposition to automatically removing things is completely undercut by the fact that we **already** remove greetings such as "hiya" at the beginning of posts. All that would be necessary is to add "so" to the list of greetings.

Comment: @torazaburo - Hmmm... `hiya` is a particular case in point. However, I still find `Hi` a number of times. The problem with `So` is that someone could _legitimately_ mean something else.... It is a little hard to think of an example off the top of my head, but maybe a typo (extra space), such as `So me times my robot does not boot`, or `SO 8 IC package fails to trigger...`. OK, it is a bit weird to start a sentence, let alone a question in such a manner, but you get my drift. Either manually editing or a gentle nudge (as you have suggested above) is probably better than a autobot.